# GRAPHQL in Mainframe DB2

Tags: graphql, db2

I'm trying to find any documentation or suggestion on possibilities of exploring Mainframe DB2 table using GRAPHQL API. We have 50+ tables that we want to explore via API. We don't want to create API for every table. Please guide if its possible to access Mainframe DB2 table via GRAPHQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too broad a question for SO but you may find this [Guide to GraphQL for SQL Developers](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1) helpful. And the short answer is yes - you can put GraphQL over DB2. Furthermore you don't need to provide access to every table  (as the guide illustrates).